# Finding the major and minor axes of an $n$-dimensional ellipse

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections

Here are two n-dimensional vectors: $V_1$ and $V_2$

$V_1 (v_1,v_2, \dots ,v_n)$

$V_2 (v_1,v_2, \dots ,v_n)$

$V_1 \cos(\theta) + V_2 \sin(\theta)$ is an ellipse in the $n$-D space. (Its center is the origin.)

I want to find the directions and magnitudes of the major and minor axes.

I have a $2$-D example here: [Ellipse with non-orthogonal minor and major axes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185718/ellipse-with-non-orthogonal-minor-and-major-axes)

People used SVD to find the minor and major axes of that $2$-D example, but I'm not familiar with SVD. So I'm having problem extending it to $n$-dimension or arbitrary $V_1$ and $V_2$.

Could anybody give a formula for it? 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It's still possible to compute the singular value decomposition of the matrix whose columns are your two vectors; the singular values will then correspond to the two axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, let's take the 3-dimensional vectors
$$ V_1 = \pmatrix{1\cr 2\cr 1\cr},\ V_2 = \pmatrix{3\cr -3\cr 2\cr} $$
With these as columns we form the matrix $$A = \pmatrix{1 & 3\cr 2 & -3\cr 1 & 2\cr}$$
Now $$ A A^T = \pmatrix{1 & 3\cr 2 & -3\cr 1 & 2\cr} \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 1\cr 3 & -3 & 2\cr} = \pmatrix{10 & -7 & 9\cr -7 & 13 & 0\cr 9 & 0 & 13\cr}$$
which has eigenvalues $23, 13, 0$ corresponding to normalized eigenvectors
$$ W_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{230}} \pmatrix{10\cr -7 \cr 9\cr},\ W_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{130}} \pmatrix{0 \cr 9\cr 7\cr},\ W_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{299}} \pmatrix{13\cr 7\cr -9\cr} $$
Note that these are orthogonal since $A A^T$ is symmetric.  The major and minor axes have
lengths $\sqrt{23}$ and $\sqrt{13}$ (the singular values, which are the square roots of the nonzero eigenvalues of $A A^T$) and directions $W_1$ and $W_2$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much. So for n-dimensional space (where n>3), Is it possible that we get more eigenvalues? Do we always pick the first two eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors as major and minor axes?

Comment: If we're talking about an ellipse, $A$ has rank $2$, so $A A^T$ has rank $2$, and there are only $2$ nonzero eigenvalues.  The largest eigenvalue gives you the major axis and the second gives you the minor axis.

Comment: Thank you very much! I get it.